# How to guard file read/write from different child processes?

Tags: c, proxy, fork, mutex

I implemented a proxy server in C using fork() for handling multiple requests from the client. I am trying to implement caching for the proxy. For that, I took the response obtained from the server and stored it into a file and I am reading that file next time that same URL is requested. But, what I suppose when one child process is writing the file to cache folder, the other is detecting that file in cache already and starting to read it. I have tried shared mutexes but they don't seem to work.

```
/*
     Web Proxy server using C
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>


#define BUFFSIZE 10240
#define MAX_PENDING 100
#define RSP_400BR "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
#define BR_MESSAGE_M "<html><body>400 Bad Request Reason: Invalid Method :<<request method>></body></html>\r\n\r\n"
#define BR_MESSAGE_U "<html><body>400 Bad Request Reason: Invalid URL: <<requested url>></body></html>\r\n\r\n"
#define CACHE_DIR "./cache/"
#define HOST_CACHE_PATH "./cache/hostname_cache.txt"

void calculate_md5sum(char* url, char* md5string);
int send_cached_file(char* url, int client_sock);
int check_file_cache(char* url);
int cache_host_ip(char* hostname, char* ip_string);
int check_host_cache(char *hostname, char* ip_string);

pthread_mutex_t file_guard;

void calculate_md5sum(char* url, char* md5string) 
{
    unsigned char url_md5[16];
    MD5((unsigned char*)url, strlen(url), url_md5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        sprintf(&md5string[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)url_md5[i]);
    }
}

int send_cached_file(char* url, int client_sock)
{
    FILE *file_ptr;
    char file_path[50];
    int read_bytes;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    char md5string[33];
    calculate_md5sum(url, md5string);
    sprintf(file_path,"%s%s", CACHE_DIR, md5string);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&file_guard);
    file_ptr = fopen(file_path, "r");
    while((read_bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_ptr))) 
    {
        send(client_sock, buffer, read_bytes, 0);
        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    }
    fclose(file_ptr);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&file_guard);
    return 0;
}

int check_file_cache(char* url) 
{
    FILE *file_ptr;
    char md5string[33];
    char file_path[50];
    calculate_md5sum(url, md5string);
    sprintf(file_path,"%s%s", CACHE_DIR, md5string);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&file_guard);
    file_ptr = fopen(file_path, "r");

    if (file_ptr == NULL) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&file_guard);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(file_ptr);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&file_guard);
        return 0;
    }
}

int cache_host_ip(char* hostname, char* ip_string) 
{
    FILE *host_cache_ptr;
    host_cache_ptr = fopen(HOST_CACHE_PATH, "a+");
    fprintf(host_cache_ptr, "%s,%s\n", hostname, ip_string);
    fclose(host_cache_ptr);
    return 0;
}

// Function to check hostname in cache for IP
int check_host_cache(char *hostname, char* ip_string) 
{
    strcpy(ip_string, "none");
    FILE *host_cache_ptr;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t length;
    host_cache_ptr = fopen(HOST_CACHE_PATH, "r");
    while((getline(&line, &length, host_cache_ptr))!=-1) {
        if (strstr(line, hostname)) {
            sscanf(line, "%*[^,]%*c%s", ip_string);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(host_cache_ptr);
    if (strcmp(ip_string, "none") == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file_ptr;
    char proxy_port[10] = "10001";
    struct sockaddr_in proxy_add;
    struct sockaddr_in client_add;
    struct sockaddr_in server_add;
    struct hostent *hp;
    unsigned int client_add_len;
    int proxy_sock, conn_sock, server_sock;
    int recv_bytes = 0;
    char request_type[10];
    char url[BUFFSIZE];
    char http_version[10];
    char host_name[100];
    char ctop_buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    char stop_buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    char ptoc_buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    int pid;
    char md5string[33];
    char file_path[50];

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s [Port]\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(proxy_port, argv[1]);
    }

    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&file_guard, &attr);

    /* build address data structure */
    bzero((char *)&proxy_add, sizeof(proxy_add));
    proxy_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    proxy_add.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    proxy_add.sin_port = htons(atoi(proxy_port));

    /* build address data structure for server */
    bzero((char *)&server_add, sizeof(server_add));
    server_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_add.sin_port = htons(atoi("80"));

    /* setup passive open */
    if ((proxy_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("\nproxy_sock creation error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((bind(proxy_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&proxy_add, sizeof(proxy_add))) < 0) 
    {
        perror("\nproxy_sock bind error");
        exit(1);
    }   

    listen(proxy_sock, MAX_PENDING);

    while(1)
    {
        client_add_len = sizeof(client_add);
        if ((conn_sock = accept(proxy_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_add, &client_add_len)) < 0) 
        {
            perror("\naccept error on proxy");
            continue;
        }

        // Fork for handling multiple connections
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) 
        {
            while(1) 
            {
                char ip_string[20];
                bzero(ctop_buffer, sizeof(ctop_buffer));
                bzero(stop_buffer, sizeof(stop_buffer));
                bzero(ptoc_buffer, sizeof(ptoc_buffer));
                recv_bytes = recv(conn_sock, ctop_buffer, sizeof(ctop_buffer), 0);
                if (recv_bytes == 0)
                {
                    printf("Request Complete\n");
                    close(conn_sock);
                    break;
                }
                sscanf(ctop_buffer, "%s %s %s", request_type, url, http_version);
                // Filter GET requests
                if (strcmp(request_type, "GET") == 0) 
                {
                    if (strstr(url, "https")) 
                    {
                        strcpy(ptoc_buffer, RSP_400BR);
                        send(conn_sock, ptoc_buffer, strlen(ptoc_buffer), 0);
                        bzero(ptoc_buffer, sizeof(ptoc_buffer));
                        strcpy(ptoc_buffer, BR_MESSAGE_U);
                        send(conn_sock, ptoc_buffer, strlen(ptoc_buffer), 0);
                        bzero(ptoc_buffer, sizeof(ptoc_buffer));
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (check_file_cache(url) == 0) 
                    {
                        printf("File found in cache\n");
                        send_cached_file(url, conn_sock);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        calculate_md5sum(url, md5string);
                        sprintf(file_path, "%s%s", CACHE_DIR, md5string);
                        printf("File NOT found in cache\n");
                        sscanf(url, "%*[^/]%*c%*c%[^/]", host_name);
                        printf("\nHostname:***%s***\n", host_name);

                        if (check_host_cache(host_name, ip_string) == 0) 
                        {
                            server_add.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_string);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            // Get IP from host name
                            hp = gethostbyname(host_name);
                            if (hp == NULL) 
                            {
                                perror("\nHost unknown");
                                continue;
                            }
                            // Copy the IP address obtained from gethostbyname() into address structure
                            bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&server_add.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
                            cache_host_ip(host_name, inet_ntoa(server_add.sin_addr));
                        }

                        /*Creating socket for communication to server*/
                        if ((server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
                        {
                            perror("\nserver_sock creation error");
                            exit(1);
                        }

                        // Connect to the server
                        if (connect(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_add, sizeof(server_add)) < 0 && errno!=EISCONN)
                        {
                            perror("\nunable to connect to host");
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Send the request obtained from client to the server
                        send(server_sock, ctop_buffer, strlen(ctop_buffer), 0);
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&file_guard);
                        file_ptr = fopen(file_path, "a");
                        // Receive response from server and send it to the client
                        while((recv_bytes = recv(server_sock, stop_buffer, sizeof(stop_buffer), 0))) 
                        {
                            printf("Recv bytes: %d\n", recv_bytes);
                            fwrite(stop_buffer, 1, recv_bytes, file_ptr);
                            send(conn_sock, stop_buffer, recv_bytes, 0);
                            bzero(stop_buffer, sizeof(stop_buffer));
                        }
                        fclose(file_ptr);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&file_guard);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    bzero(ptoc_buffer, sizeof(ptoc_buffer));
                    strcpy(ptoc_buffer, RSP_400BR);
                    send(conn_sock, ptoc_buffer, strlen(ptoc_buffer), 0);
                    bzero(ptoc_buffer, sizeof(ptoc_buffer));
                    strcpy(ptoc_buffer, BR_MESSAGE_M);
                    send(conn_sock, ptoc_buffer, strlen(ptoc_buffer), 0);
                }

            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am storing the files as md5sum of the URL that requested it

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any mutexes un your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry, I uploaded a previous version, I have edited my code to include mutexes

Comment: By shared mutexes you mean named semaphores? I have used them in the past and they do work... Also you could lock the file itself or use lock files, but that depends on your system / storage.

Comment: First thing to do: add error checking to all your mutex related code. All those `pthread_*` functions may fail.

Comment: @FernandoCoelho No, its just that I intend to let all child processes know that a particular mutex is locked or unlocked, for that it needs to be shared between all child processes formed by fork()

Comment: @MukundMadhusudanAtre the thing is that you do not have shared memory on your code, when you fork the child process will have their own instance of the file lock which is not shared with the parent. It would work with threads, but not with fork. If you want a lock that will be shared, you need to use a named semaphore instead.

Comment: File locking would be sufficient, either BSD file locking (`flock()`) or POSIX file locking (`fcntl()`)/

Comment: Using `fork` as a mechanism to multiplex sockets has been outdated since at least the late nineties. Threads are vastly superior in performance, and you might find unless you're handling multiple hundreds of thousands of connections simultaneously you'll probably find asynchronous or non-blocking modes will be faster yet. Google "the C10k problem".